# Error when creating raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

Version 3.16.0 Hannover
I am trying to create a simple raster from x,y,z data
Using Raster-->>Analysis-->>Grid (IDW)
Please see the error log below:
Can anyone help?

> QGIS version: 3.16.0-Hannover QGIS code revision: 43b64b13f3 Qt
> version: 5.11.2 GDAL version: 3.1.4 GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
> PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020 Processing algorithm…
> Algorithm 'Grid (Inverse distance to a power)' starting… Input
> parameters: { 'ANGLE' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' :
> 'delimitedtext://file:///C:/Users/david/Desktop/Collars.csv?type=csv&skipLines=9&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=138650&yField=141360&zField=40&crs=EPSG:29902&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no',
> 'MAX_POINTS' : 0, 'MIN_POINTS' : 0, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '',
> 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'POWER' : 2, 'RADIUS_1' : 0, 'RADIUS_2'
> : 0, 'SMOOTHING' : 0, 'Z_FIELD' : '40' }
>
> GDAL command: gdal_grid -l None -zfield 40 -a
> invdist:power=2.0:smothing=0.0:radius1=0.0:radius2=0.0:angle=0.0:max_points=0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0
> -ot Float32 -of GTiff "file:///C:/Users/david/Desktop/Collars.csv?type=csv&skipLines=9&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=138650&yField=141360&zField=40&crs=EPSG:29902&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
> C:/Users/david/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_aiDgiu/cb24c708989444ecba3f22bda635ddd0/OUTPUT.tif
> GDAL command output: ERROR 4:
> `file:///C:/Users/david/Desktop/Collars.csv?type=csv&skipLines=9&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=138650&yField=141360&zField=40&crs=EPSG:29902&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'
> does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a
> supported dataset name.
>
> Execution completed in 0.14 seconds Results: {'OUTPUT':
> 'C:/Users/david/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_aiDgiu/cb24c708989444ecba3f22bda635ddd0/OUTPUT.tif'}
>
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
> generated. •
> C:/Users/david/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_aiDgiu/cb24c708989444ecba3f22bda635ddd0/OUTPUT.tif
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
> more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Gdal_grid https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html gets this filename as an input `"file:///C:/Users/david/Desktop/Collars.csv?type=csv&skipLines=9&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=138650&yField=141360&zField=40&crs=EPSG:29902&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"` It probably awaits just `C:/Users/david/Desktop/Collars.csv`.